# Proving an inequality from given condition.

Tags: inequality

Given:

$$\frac{m^2}{n^2}<2 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{(m+2n)^2}{(m+n)^2}>2$$

I want to prove:

$$\frac{(m+2n)^2}{(m+n)^2}-2<2-\frac{m^2}{n^2}$$

Is it possible to directly prove final inequality using the given conditions by simple addition/subtraction and reasoning rather than simplification of the expressions?

EDIT: The direction of the inequality sign in the final inequality was wrong. Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious...
$$\frac{(m+2n)^2}{(m+n)^2} - 2
=\frac{2n^2 - m^2}{(m+n)^2} 
\leq \frac{2n^2-m^2}{n^2}
= 2 - \frac{m^2}{n^2}
$$
where the inequality relies on the assumption $|m+n| \geq |n|$, (I assumed $m,n \geq 0$ so this was trivially satisfied)

Comment: Nice! Just for completeness, your inequality also requires  $2 n^2 > m^2$ which however is given by the original first condition. Technically, you would also have to guarantee that the second original condition is also satisfied (which is the case).

Comment: It might be a bit off topic, but can I ask you how you came up with this solution? I mean in terms of thought process?

Comment: @Andreas, good catch. Gotta keep that numerator non-negative.

Comment: @Rio1210, literally just worked out the algebra on both sides and the denominators happen to behave well.